# ActiveMQ sometimes loses message property when using broker redelivery plugin

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

We are using ActiveMQ 5.8.0 in combination with Spring JMS 3.2.3.RELEASE. The application listens to a queue using the Spring `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, and objects are stored in an `ActiveMQTextMessage` using the Spring `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`.

We also use the ActiveMQ broker redelivery plugin, which is configured in `activemq.xml`. Messages are persisted in an Oracle database, also configured in `activemq.xml`.

Now we have the following problem: in about 60% of the messages that are redelivered, the `javaClass` property that is set on the message by the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` is missing. This causes the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not find type id property [javaClass]
            at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.getJavaTypeForMessage(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:360)
            at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:176)
```

When examining the persisted messages in our database we see that the `javaClass` property is indeed missing. But the `redeliveryDelay` and `AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` properties that are set by the `RedeliveryPlugin` are present.

Could this be caused by a bug in ActiveMQ? I see that `RedeliveryPlugin.scheduleRedelivery()` sets the `marshalledProperties` to null, which should be correct behaviour to ensure that all properties are serialised in `Message.beforeMarshall()`. But if the properties are created lazily and no method that creates them (i.e. `getProperty()` or some such) has been called yet, then nulling the `marshalledProperties` wipes out properties that have been set before the redelivery plugin.

The following unit test proves that this scenario is possible with the current implementation of `org.apache.activemq.command.Message`:

```java
@Test
public void testGetPropertyAfterUnmarshallAndNullMarshalledProperties() throws IOException {
    ActiveMQTextMessage msg = new ActiveMQTextMessage();
    msg.setProperty(TYPEID_PROPERTY, TEST_CLASS);

    OpenWireFormat wireFormat = new OpenWireFormat(CommandTypes.PROTOCOL_VERSION);
    msg.beforeMarshall(wireFormat);

    ByteSequence byteSequence = wireFormat.marshal(msg);

    ActiveMQTextMessage unmarshalled = (ActiveMQTextMessage) wireFormat.unmarshal(byteSequence);

    // simulate RedeliveryPlugin behaviour
    unmarshalled.setMarshalledProperties(null);

    assertNull(unmarshalled.getProperty(TYPEID_PROPERTY));
}
```

Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour when using the broker redelivery plugin? We started using the broker plugin because we were experiencing problems with the client redelivery mechanism, so going back to that is not an option.

Comment: I am also seeing this.